# What is the best stat armor for a necromancer doing condition damage?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have a necromancer that does condition damage.  What is the best armor for this type of necro?  It seems that the best armor would be the Grenth Karma Exotic armor that I can get from the Temple of Grenth in the Cursed Shore, right?  That armor seems to increase condition damage with every piece you wear.  Is there better one?  Thanks.

EDIT:
Thought I would add these guides...

http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/80743-massive-guides-for-condition-necromancer-pve-wvw-fractals/

http://lopezirl.com/2012/12/19/a-condition-necromancers-guide-to-pve/

http://lopezirl.com/2012/12/30/a-condition-necromancers-guide-to-world-vs-world/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're willing to buy exotic armor with `karma`, then indeed, the [Mortal armor of Grenth](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mortal_armor_of_Grenth) sold in Temple of Grenth seems a good option. If you're looking for `runes` which cause condition damage, you can check them [here](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Runes#Condition_Damage).

Another interesting [dungeon armors](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/List_of_armor_sets#Dungeon_armor_sets) with different attributes you could take a look:

- [Flame Legion armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Flame_Legion_armor_%28light%29)

  - `Condition Damage` + `Power` + `Vitality` (+315 / +224 / +224 Attributes)
- [Sorrow's Embrace armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sorrow%27s_Embrace_armor)

  - `Power`    +   `Vitality`  +   `Condition Damage` (+315 / +224 / +224 Attributes)
- [Corrupted armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Corrupted_armor)

  - `Precision` + `Toughness` + `Condition Damage` (+224 / +224 / +315 Attributes)
- [Nightmare armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Nightmare_armor)

  - `Condition Damage`     +   `Toughness`     +   `Precision` (+315 / +224 / +224 Attributes)
  - `Precision`    +   `Power`     +   `Condition Damage` (+315 / +224 / +224 Attributes)
- [Inquest armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Inquest_armor)

  - `Power`   +   `Precision`     +   `Condition Damage` ( +224 / +315 / +214 Attributes )
  - `Power`    +   `Condition Damage`  +   `Magic Find` (+224 / +224 / +18%)
- [Noble's armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Noble%27s_armor)

  - 3 combinations with `Condition damage` as a 224 atribute
- [Honor of the Waves armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Honor_of_the_Waves_armor)

  - `Precision`   +   `Toughness`     +   `Condition Damage`  (+315 / +224 / +224 Attributes)
- [Corrupted armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Corrupted_armor)

  - `Precision`    +   `Toughness`     +   `Condition Damage` (+224 / +224 / +315 Attributes)

You may also would like to take a look in [Ogden's armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ogden%27s_armor) and [Khilbron's armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Khilbron%27s_armor)

Resuming: There are several sets which contain condition damage, you may choose one that fits more your play style.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative answer!  This is just what I needed.

Comment: The dungeon armor seems a better deal, right?  The reason I say this is the Dungeon Exotic armor has free upgrade slots, but the MAoGrenth does not.  The MAoG has condition damage of 125+28+55+100 or 318.  However the Flame Legion Exotic armor has condition damage of 315 and I could add runes to it increasing the Condition damage even more, right?

Comment: It's interesting because I knew how to answer this because recently I was looking for armor for my Ranger too, I'm looking for Critical Damage, I chose to buy the karma armor (Lyssa) because the bonuses and precision were good, and it has very diferent stats. But I've already transmuted some parts of it.

Comment: I believe Dungeon armor also comes with runes. I'm not really quite sure if the only way to attach runes to these piece of armours is transmuting (with transmuting stone). Anyway, I believe you're right, it would be a good idea to buy the Flame Legion Exotic and then attach a rune like you feel its better. I chose the karma

Comment: I chose the karma path because I had a lot and it was a quick way to get a set, and as I said before, I liked the stats of the rune that came together. But maybe in the future I'll change. I think that if you're going to a full condition damage that's the way. Sorry for the loooong comments.

Comment: Thanks again for the advice.  You're right, I just double checked the wiki and the flame legion armor you linked to has a Superior Rune of the Baelfire in each armor slot.  My mistake.